# Слитно или раздельно не с причастием (прилагательным)

Tags: орфография, частица-не, слитно-раздельно

Данная версия браузера содержит самые свежие нововведения, пока (не)отлаженные процессы, (не)пофиксенные ошибки.

Comment: "пофиксенные" - это даже не сленг, это издевательство над русским языком

Comment: Версия браузера содержит **процессы** (?!)

Comment: Да, меняется язык, это нормально. Не претендую на литературный и школу давно окончила (в сочинениях такое не пишу).

Сам браузер содержит кучу процессов,  включает. 
Интересует написание Не, а не структура предложения.

Comment: Вы вопрос толком не потрудились сформулировать, а именно там и надо было предупреждать об интересах, тем более экзотических (здесь читать, а здесь не читать).

Answer (score 1):

*Данная версия браузера содержит самые свежие нововведения, пока  не отлаженные процессы, непофиксенные ошибки.*

Если говорить только о русском языке, о слитном/раздельном написании НЕ, то в первом случае есть зависимое слово ПОКА, значит, это причастие, пишется раздельно, во втором случае, вероятно, прилагательное, зависимых слов нет.

Термина такого не знаю, могу только предположить: пофиксенные = отлаженные, исправленные, непофиксенные = неотлаженные. Если так, то и пишется так же, как неотлаженные, слитно.

Comment: Ошибки не могут быть отлажены, они могут быть исправлены. Чем лучше "пофиксить" по сравнению с "исправить" - не знаю. Формально Вы правы: нужно писать "непофиксенные".

Comment: Людмила, а, на ваш взгляд, самые свежие новшества (=нововведения) — нормальное с точки зрения культуры речи словосочетание?

Comment: "Пока " относится  и к неотлаженные,  и непофиксенные. По правилам РЯ вроде раздельно, но является ли малюсенькое слово "пока"(вместо него можно написать слово "еще") - тем самым объясняющим оборотом. 

Предложение из дневника. Оно не обязано быть литературным.

Comment: Пока = ещё - наречие, зависимое слово, хоть и малюсенькое, влияет на раздельное написание, только мне кажется, что оно относится только к "не отлаженные".

Answer (score 0):

Фразу желательно перестроить, например так:

**Данная версия браузера содержит самые свежие нововведения, но пока не отлажена.**

А про ошибки и так понятно.

--Добавление--

Даю другую версию ответа, учитывая просьбу автора не редактировать фразу и пояснение, что по замыслу автора "пока" относится не тольно к *неотлаженным*, но и к *непофиксенным*.

**Данная версия браузера содержит самые свежие нововведения, пока не отлаженные процессы, не пофиксенные ошибки.**

По-моему, *отлаженные* и *пофиксенные* - это причастия. *Не* с причастиями пишется раздельно ввиду наличия поясняющего слова "пока".

Comment: М_Г, а, на ваш взгляд, самые свежие новшества (=нововведения) — нормальное с точки зрения культуры речи словосочетание?

Comment: По-моему, "самые свежие нововведения" допустимы в той же мере, что и "самые свежие новости".

Comment: ...в рамках разговорного стиля.

Comment: Можно задать еще вопрос: насколько уместно говорить о "нововведениях" в браузере. Возможно, автор употребляет это слово по отношению к любым изменениям - и тогда это ошибка. Вряд ли изменения действительно соответствуют понятию  "нововведение"

Comment: Суть в правописании. Фраза из дневника. Имеется ввиду версия браузера Chrome Canary - для разработчиков, каждый час она обновляется и нестабильна, может вылетать, а новые фишечки в ней есть